# Positivity of the weak * limit in $L^{\infty}$.

Tags: real-analysis, weak-convergence

Assume $\{f_n\}$ is the sequence where $0 \leq f_n \in L^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^3)$.
Now suppose $f$ is the weak * limit of $\{f_n\}$ in $L^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^3)$.

Can I derive $f \geq 0$?

I think it might be true by taking the sign function on measurable sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deduce that
$$\tag1
\int_{\mathbb R^3} fg\geq0\qquad \text{ for all } g\in L^1(\mathbb R^3),\ g\geq0. 
$$
This is enough to show that $f\geq0$ a.e.: if $f<0$ on any finite-measure set $E$, then if $E$ has positive measure you get from  $(1)$
$$
0>\int_Ef=\int f\,1_E\geq0, 
$$
a contradiction. So $E$ is a nullset, and so $f\geq0 $ a.e.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1